# friendly url , yii2 urlManager how to use. (does not work)

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, yii2

I have test project on yii2. 
I have 2 controllers 1st default (SiteController) 2nd called CountryController. Url for request 2nd controller looks like localhost/testYii/?r=country i need change url as follows --> localhost/testYii/country.

It's my urlmanager config

```
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName'=>false,
           'rules' => [
                'country'=>'country',

            ],
            // ...
        ],
```

localhost/testYii/country --> onject not found

If I understand correctly 'country'=>'country'
1st it's how will be look own url and 2nd is name of controller (CountryController)  which will be called.

And question why is it doesn't work ? :(

And my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ basic/web/
```

Answer (score 0):

With your controller you need to provide the view that you want to display.

Example:

```
localhost/testYii/country/index
```